# send push notification form my server PHP

Tags: php, iphone, sockets, apple-push-notifications

I'am trying to send push notification from my localhost to my iDevices all work properly but in the PHP error log I got the warning below Why ?

**NOTE: I receive the Push on all Devices**

**THE WARNING:**

```
PHP Warning:  socket_close(): supplied resource is not a valid Socket resource in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/Push/SendPush.php on line xxx
```

Some of My Code:

```
//....
$streamContext = stream_context_create();
stream_context_set_option($streamContext, 'ssl', 'local_cert', $apnsCert);

$apns = stream_socket_client('ssl://' . $apnsHost . ':' . $apnsPort, $error, $errorString, 2, STREAM_CLIENT_CONNECT, $streamContext);
//...

socket_close($apns);
fclose($apns);
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Most likely Apple is terminating the connection after it receives your payload.

To silence the warning make the following change:

```
@socket_close($apns);
```

Answer (score 1):

`stream_socket_client()` returns false if there was an error. You should explicitly test for it:

```
$apns = stream_socket_client(...);
if ($apns === FALSE) then
    die("Error while getting stream socket ($error): $errorString");
}
```

where $error/$errorString are the ones you've specified in the stream_socket_client() call.

Comment: hello i added ur code if(...){} else{echo "..."}; I got the else echoing witch mean $apns == True, and I still got the warning